# How do I display 4 different outputs with HDMI when I only have one input device?

Tags: streaming, software-recommendation, screen-casting, hdmi, television

I have one laptop with 4 different applications running on it. I would like to separate these 4 applications into each television. Each television will display one of the applications. I have bought 1 HDMI transmitter and 4 HDMI Receivers for the television. However, I was under the impression that I can separate the 4 applications for each television. This turned out to be false.